# Crawling published content with Nutch on LinkedIn

Tags: web-crawler

I'm new to crawling and can you please let me know if we can crawl published content (not user specific data) on LinkedIn with Apache Nutch?

I have setup Nutch with Solr and I am successfully able to crawl sites but when I try to crawl LinkedIn I get the message "No more URLs to fetch". This must be because LinkedIn has denied crawling of its pages I suppose. Is there any other way to do so?.

Comment: Can you edit into your question some more details about your Nutch config? The reason you cite _may_ be the case, but without more details it is difficult to say. It is possible though: what sort of delay are you putting in between requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nutch is not white-listed in their Robots.txt file and the default is

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Which means, no crawling.

They do have a comment in their robots.txt file

> Notice: If you would like to crawl LinkedIn,
>   please email whitelistcrawl@linkedin.com to apply 
>   for white listing.

However I don't think they will agree to white-list Nutch.
You would have to

1. Set a different UA on Nutch
2. E-mail them and explain why you want to crawl them and get your UA whitelisted.